# Unexpected token >

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

The script used to work before, now it suddenly doesnt. It returns a unexpected token > error which makes no sense cause I haven't edited anything here, but when removing the other code I added it still doesn't work. And the button doesn't trigger the code now after I tried fixing it, but that's another problem. Can you guys see why?

```
function dologin() {
    var senddata = $('#form').serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'herpaderp',
        data: senddata,
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {
            if (response.success == true)
                window.location.href = "herpderp";
            else if (response.success == false)
                navigator.notification.alert("Feil brukernavn eller passord", null, "Mislykket innlogging", "OK");
            else
                alert("Noe gikk galt, kontakt administrator");
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log("Status: " + textStatus);
            console.log("Error: " + errorThrown);
        }
    });
    return false;
};
```

Comment: Sounds like your `url` can't be loaded.

Comment: Check *what* the servers answers (network tab or a packet inspector such as Fiddler2). It's responding in HTML (probably because of a server error).

Comment: The url is just erased out because I don't want to share it.

Comment: Its because of the error in your backend, The dataType returned is not json, check your error logs

Comment: I just checked now and everything on the server works fine, and the response is JSON. This code is ran from my phone, but it shouldn't matter.

Comment: Make sure your senddata is identical to when you get the problem. Perhaps you're missing a `$_POST` variable when using `.serialize()`.

Comment: Why are you not using 'jsonp' if this is a cross-domain request?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Seems to work now, somehow it was my HTML code that was broken. Thanks for the help guys!